# Is this an efficient sql server query?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

If I write a sproc in this format, will sql server do this effeciently or should the sql 'weaving' be done on the server side (.net)?

Note: this is just a rough idea of what my query looks like, there are more 'if' clauses the build up my query that I execute using 'exec'

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
declare @order nvarchar(4000)


set @sql = 'select id, name'
set @sql = @sql + ' ....' 

if(@sortOrder)
    set @order = 'order by name desc'

exec @sql + @order
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of building up a SQL string, why not just use a case statement in the order by?

e.g. (assuming one is sorting by first and/or last name on a table with FirstName and LastName fields)

```
order by
  case 
  when @sortExpression = 'lastname asc' then CAST(LastName as sql_variant)
  when @sortExpression = 'firstname asc' then CAST(FirstName as sql_variant)
  end asc,
  case
  when @sortExpression = 'lastname desc' then CAST(LastName as sql_variant)
  when @sortExpression = 'firstname desc' then CAST(FirstName as sql_variant)
  end desc
```

In addition, if your order by clause is different each time via dynamic SQL, the query plan will never be re-used.

Comment: The type of the columns must be the same (NULL the unused ones):
ORDER BY 
 CASE @Order WHEN 1 THEN [DateOfBirth] ELSE NULL END
, CASE @Order WHEN 2 THEN [DateOfBirth] ELSE NULL END DESC
, CASE @Order WHEN 3 THEN [LastName] ELSE NULL END
, CASE @Order WHEN 4 THEN [LastName] ELSE NULL END DESC

Comment: No they don't. As long as you CAST to sql_variant, the columns can all be of different types in the same CASE and you don't need to set anything to NULL. Try it, it works. I've done this many times.

Comment: If you cast to sql_variant, the sorting logic will be string-based, so numeric values will not be sorted as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The clearest, simplest, easiest, most optimizable way is to have complete SQL statements for each option.

Answer (score 1):

I see two better ways to do this.  Instead of using a dynamic SQL query, I would use an actual SQL statement in a stored procedure, cased by the things you want to order by:

```
select
  t.* 
from 
  table as t 
order by
  case @val
    when 1 then column1
    when 2 then column2
  end
```

If you find that the order by is too dynamic and must be built up, or is easer to do so, then I would create a table-valued function which returns the set, and then create a dynamic sql statement against that:

```
select
  t.*
from
  xfn_Function(@arg1, @arg2) as t
order by
  t.col1, t.col2
```

Where of course, t.col1, t.col2, etc, etc, are dynamically generated before you send the whole thing to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a good reason for doing this as dynamic SQL?

I've done what you have before in SQL server and it works fine; it's probably safer (depending on usage) than passing in fully formed SQL to a proc that just runs it blindly.

If you're using SQL 2k5 or 2k8, you can use nvarchar(max) for longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question, there will be no performance difference at all between a dynamic SQL statement which is formed in your .Net layer, and exactly the same SQL string which is formed inside a proc.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is to get whatever data you want from the database and then handle the sorting in your application. Changing the order by isn't going to change the amount of data. If the user changes the sort order, why make another trip to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic query performance is almost equivalent to server side weaving. if you can not find any other way to avoid dynamic query, nest it in server side.

following also works in case you do not have many "ifs"

```
if(@sortorder = 'name') select id, name from tbl order by name asc
if(@sortorder = 'id') select id, name from tbl order by id asc
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

It compiles in the "exec" command.  The speed difference should be minimal between that, and doing it all on .NET side.

At some point and time, it compiles the SQL to some internal code.  It can happen as .NET pushes it, or afterwards.

Answer (score -5):

I would build the rest of the query up to the order by ie.

```
@sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM myTable ORDER BY ' + @order
```

... and pass the column name and direction to the proc. That way is more secure because not much can be passed to an order by clause to cause any harm.

To answer your question, yes, it is efficient.

Comment: >> because not much can be passed to an order by clause to cause any harm.

Wow, just wow

Comment: Bad idea, however, alternatively, you could pass in the order by as an integer, and then based on the value of that integer, sort by a list of predefined columns corresponding to those integer values.

Comment: Can I order your tables by "name; DROP TABLE myTable" please?

Comment: -1 - for the "That way is more secure because not much can be passed to an order by clause to cause any harm." statement.
;update employees set salary=0 where employee='orthod0ks';--

Comment: I would hope you're all checking for injection attacks at the input level.